# Выбор данных из нескольких таблиц с основным ключём

Tags: sql, запрос

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой, код написан, работает хорошо. Нужно доработать до совершенства.

Вот код:

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT v1.nr, v1.kokyb_pre_kod AS ID, v1.prod_vadovas_pre_pav AS Pavadinimas, v1.pre_rus, v1.pre_poz1, v1.pre_poz2, v1.kada_sukurtas, v1.sveik_teig AS Sveik_Teiginys, 
                     CASE WHEN prod_vadovas_vp = '' OR
                     prod_vadovas_vp IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'X' END AS Pr_vad, CASE WHEN kokyb_vadovas_vp = '' OR
                     kokyb_vadovas_vp IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'X' END AS Kok_vad, CASE WHEN market_vadovas_vp = '' OR
                     market_vadovas_vp IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'X' END AS Mark_vad, CASE WHEN mak.maketas IS NOT NULL AND mak.patvirtino_1 IS NOT NULL AND mak.patvirtino_1 != '' THEN 'Yra/Patv' WHEN mak.maketas IS NOT NULL AND 
                     (mak.patvirtino_1 = '' OR
                     mak.patvirtino_1 IS NULL) THEN 'Yra/NePatv' WHEN (v1.maketas = '0' OR
                     v1.maketas IS NULL) AND (mak.maketas = '' OR
                     mak.maketas IS NULL) THEN 'Neaktualu' WHEN (v1.maketas = '0' OR
                     v1.maketas IS NULL) THEN 'Neaktualu' WHEN mak.maketas = '' OR
                     mak.maketas IS NULL THEN 'Nėra' END AS Maketas, 
                     
                     CASE WHEN vok.vokelis IS NOT NULL AND vok.patvirtino_1 IS NOT NULL AND vok.patvirtino_1 != '' THEN 'Yra/Patv' WHEN vok.vokelis IS NOT NULL AND 
                     (vok.patvirtino_1 = '' OR
                     vok.patvirtino_1 IS NULL) THEN 'Yra/NePatv' WHEN (v1.vokelis = '0' OR
                     v1.vokelis IS NULL) AND (vok.vokelis = '' OR
                     vok.vokelis IS NULL) THEN 'Neaktualu' WHEN (v1.vokelis = '0' OR
                     v1.vokelis IS NULL) THEN 'Neaktualu' WHEN vok.vokelis = '' OR
                     vok.vokelis IS NULL THEN 'Nėra' END AS Vokelis, 
                     
                     
                     CASE WHEN wor.word IS NOT NULL AND wor.patvirtino_1 IS NOT NULL AND wor.patvirtino_1 != '' THEN 'Yra/Patv' WHEN wor.word IS NOT NULL AND (wor.patvirtino_1 = '' OR
                     wor.patvirtino_1 IS NULL) THEN 'Yra/NePatv' WHEN (v1.wordas = '0' OR
                     v1.wordas IS NULL) AND (wor.word = '' OR
                     wor.word IS NULL) THEN 'Neaktualu' WHEN (v1.wordas = '0' OR
                     v1.wordas IS NULL) THEN 'Neaktualu' WHEN wor.word = '' OR
                     wor.word IS NULL THEN 'Nėra' END AS Word, CASE WHEN lip.lipdukas IS NOT NULL AND lip.patvirtino_1 IS NOT NULL AND lip.patvirtino_1 != '' THEN 'Yra/Patv' WHEN lip.lipdukas IS NOT NULL AND (lip.patvirtino_1 = '' OR
                     lip.patvirtino_1 IS NULL) THEN 'Yra/NePatv' WHEN (v1.lipdukas = '0' OR
                     v1.lipdukas IS NULL) AND (lip.lipdukas = '' OR
                     lip.lipdukas IS NULL) THEN 'Neaktualu' WHEN (v1.lipdukas = '0' OR
                     v1.lipdukas IS NULL) THEN 'Neaktualu' WHEN lip.lipdukas = '' OR
                     lip.lipdukas IS NULL THEN 'Nėra' END AS Lipdukas, CASE WHEN efsa.efsa IS NOT NULL AND efsa.patvirtino_1 IS NOT NULL AND efsa.patvirtino_1 != '' THEN 'Yra/Patv' WHEN efsa.efsa IS NOT NULL AND 
                     (efsa.patvirtino_1 = '' OR
                     efsa.patvirtino_1 IS NULL) THEN 'Yra/NePatv' WHEN (v1.efsa = '0' OR
                     v1.efsa IS NULL) AND (efsa.efsa = '' OR
                     efsa.efsa IS NULL) THEN 'Neaktualu' WHEN (v1.efsa = '0' OR
                     v1.efsa IS NULL) THEN 'Neaktualu' WHEN efsa.efsa = '' OR
                     efsa.efsa IS NULL THEN 'Nėra' END AS EFSA, CASE WHEN fin.pre_kod IS NULL OR
                     fin.pre_kod = '' THEN 'Ne' ELSE 'TAIP' END AS Finvalda_ID, v1.PRE_POZ9
    FROM            (SELECT        nr, kokyb_pre_kod, prod_vadovas_pre_pav, kada_sukurtas, sveik_teig, prod_vadovas_vp, kokyb_vadovas_vp, market_vadovas_vp, perkeltas, wordas, maketas, vokelis, lipdukas, efsa, 
                                                prod_vadovas_pre_poz1 AS pre_poz1, prod_vadovas_pre_poz2 AS pre_poz2, prod_vadovas_pre_rus AS pre_rus, prod_vadovas_pre_poz9 AS PRE_POZ9
                      FROM            dbo.Priedas_4_v1) AS v1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         (SELECT        pre_kod, pre_rus, pre_poz1, pre_poz2, PRE_POZ9
                           FROM            dbo.View_Prekes_pavadinimas_Finvalda) AS fin ON v1.kokyb_pre_kod = fin.pre_kod LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         
                         (SELECT top 1 nr_pagr, pre_pav AS vokelis, patvirtino_1
                        
                           FROM            dbo.Priedas_4_Failai
                           WHERE        (pre_pav = 'Galutinis Vokelis') AND (aktualus = 'TAIP') 
                           
                          ORDER BY patvirtino_1
                           
                           
                           ) AS vok ON v1.nr = vok.nr_pagr 
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         (SELECT        nr_pagr, pre_pav AS maketas, patvirtino_1
                           FROM            dbo.Priedas_4_Failai AS Priedas_4_Failai_2
                           WHERE        (pre_pav = 'Galutinis Maketas') AND (aktualus = 'TAIP')) AS mak ON v1.nr = mak.nr_pagr LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         (SELECT        nr_pagr, pre_pav AS word, patvirtino_1
                           FROM            dbo.Priedas_4_Failai AS Priedas_4_Failai_1
                           WHERE        (pre_pav = 'WORD Ženklinimas') AND (aktualus = 'TAIP')) AS wor ON v1.nr = wor.nr_pagr LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         (SELECT        nr_pagr, pre_pav AS lipdukas, patvirtino_1, aktualus
                           FROM            dbo.Priedas_4_Failai AS Priedas_4_Failai_4
                           WHERE        (pre_pav = 'Galutinis Lipdukas') AND (aktualus = 'TAIP')) AS lip ON v1.nr = lip.nr_pagr LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         (SELECT        nr_pagr, pre_pav AS efsa, patvirtino_1
                           FROM            dbo.Priedas_4_Failai AS Priedas_4_Failai_3
                           WHERE        (pre_pav = 'EFSA Teiginiai') AND (aktualus = 'TAIP')) AS efsa ON v1.nr = efsa.nr_pagr
    WHERE        (v1.perkeltas IS NULL) AND v1.nr=2378
```

В данном случае когда на 46 строке делаю select top 1 не находит, Galutinis Vokelis, связь идёт через nr_pagr,
но если в том же подзапросе написать какой мне номер нужен тогда выдаёт нужную строку например

```
SELECT top 1 nr_pagr, pre_pav AS vokelis, patvirtino_1
                        
                           FROM            dbo.Priedas_4_Failai
                           WHERE        (pre_pav = 'Galutinis Vokelis') AND (aktualus = 'TAIP') AND nr_pagr=2378
                           
                          ORDER BY patvirtino_1
```

, а без этого пишет, что нет такой строки.

Если убрать ТОП1, то всё работает на ура, до тех пор пока в файлах нет 2 строк с тем же главным ключём, тогда в общем списке дублирует позиции, а мне нужно всё в одной строке.

Как можно научить выбрать ТОП 1 только той позиции, с которой есть связь?

Comment: Вы правда думаете, что кому-то доставит радость разбираться в этой неформатированной портянке? Неужели сложно создать небольшую, но адекватную, модель из 2-3 таблиц по 2-3 поля?

Comment: *как можно научить выбрать ТОП 1 только той позиции с которой есть связь ?* Коррелированный WHERE EXISTS в него вместо внешнего ON - и соответственно INNER JOIN.

Comment: я вроде выделил то место что мне не понятно. если через where, то если ничего в файлах не будет добавлено, он вообще не покажет этой строки.

Comment: Именно поэтому появился второй комментарий. Иначе и его бы не было.

Comment: Я проверяю добавлено или нет что то в файлах, а если добавлено много файлов нужен только топ1 потверждённый